# Configuring HttpClient in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have configured `HttpClient` for multiple typed clients within the `Program.cs` of my .NET Core 7 API project, this way:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService1, Service1>
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttphandler() {UseCookies= false});
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService2, Service2>
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttphandler() {UseCookies= false});
```

Underneath this I also have this code:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService2, Service2>();
```

`HttpClient` object gets injected correctly within my 2 service classes and I am calling another external API using this injected `HttpClient` and it's all working fine.

Questions:

1. Right now I am running the above application in *http* mode locally. Does using the code above pose any issues when I deploy the above code to run under *https*? I have read somewhere that using `SocketsHttpHandler` instead of `HttpClienthandler` may pose some TLS version issues.
2. Even though it is all working fine, is it OK to `AddHttpClient` block of code (above) before the `AddSingleton` block for the 2 service classes in `Program.cs`?
3. Is there any way I can code the `.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler()` part of the code above just once for all Typed Clients? I am repeating that line for every `AddHttpClient` line. Tomorrow we may have 100's of service classes and I hate to repeat it 100 times.

Thanks.

Comment: You must have read a 10-year old article because Sockets is the default handler.  HttpClient works with HTTPS just fine - by now all sites use HTTPS. You can remove the call to `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` unless you want to disable cookies. Even then, it's better to configure the HttpClientHandler

Comment: Thanks for your response @PanagiotisKanavos! That is exactly the issue I am having. I am reading old links and getting all confused. Yes, I have to disable the cookies as I don't want the CookieContainer to cache my cookies between two requests. Besides, I am setting the cookie in the Request header when I call the other API.

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? They show [how to disable cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookies). As for not repeating code, `AddHttpClient` is an extension method. So is `Configure...`. You can create your own that does the same thing

Comment: `AddSingleton` is a bug here - it means your service will try to use the same HttpClient instance forever. AddHttpClient already registered it as Transient. Why make it Singleton?

Comment: That's the exact code (in the article) I have above to disable the cookies. Yes, I created a extension method on IServiceCollection to add all my typed clients. Thanks though!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. I am not adding HttpClient again as Singleton. I am adding HttpClient only once as transient, as we can see in the code above. But just the DI part of the Service classes uses the Singleton configuration. My question was about the order of the 2 in program.cs. Should I add HttpClient block of code after the AddSingleton block or does it matter at all.

Comment: `.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>()` is a bug. It will take a single HttpClient instance and keep using it. If the DNS settings changes, eg because a server went down, the service will keep trying to connect to the old IP. `AddHttpClient` already registered `Service1` as a transient. Why make it singleton?

Comment: Oh OK. I get it now. I thought registering HttpClient with a Typed Client (as Transient) and registering the type itself in DI are two separate things.  Thanks a lot for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

For question 3, you could easily extract a small function, something like

```
static void AddHttpClient<TInterface, TService>(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddHttpClient<TInterface, TService>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttphandler() {UseCookies= false});
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Duh. I should have thought of this. Thanks @sfuqua!